# beaglebone black adc "in_voltageX_raw': Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: beagleboneblack, adc, debian-buster

I struggle to get readings from analog inputs on the bbb.

cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage5_raw
cat: '/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage5_raw': Resource temporarily unavailable

cat /etc/dogtag
BeagleBoard.org Debian Buster Console Image 2020-05-18

uname -a
Linux beaglebone 5.4.38-ti-r8 #1buster SMP PREEMPT Sat May 9 09:53:15 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

sudo /opt/scripts/tools/version.sh

```
git:/opt/scripts/:[029041f6866049997bbfd2c7667b3c6e8c95201c]
eeprom:[A335BNLT000C1716BBBG0543]
model:[TI_AM335x_BeagleBone_Black]
dogtag:[BeagleBoard.org Debian Buster Console Image 2020-05-18]
bootloader:[microSD-(push-button)]:[/dev/mmcblk0]:[U-Boot 2019.04-00002-g31a8ae0206]:[location: dd MBR]
bootloader:[eMMC-(default)]:[/dev/mmcblk1]:[U-Boot 2019.04-00002-g07d5700e21]:[location: dd MBR]
UBOOT: Booted Device-Tree:[am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dts]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[BB-ADC-00A0]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[BB-BONE-eMMC1-01-00A0]
kernel:[5.4.38-ti-r8]
/boot/uEnv.txt Settings:
uboot_overlay_options:[enable_uboot_overlays=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_video=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0.dtbo]
uboot_overlay_options:[enable_uboot_cape_universal=1]
pkg check: to individually upgrade run: [sudo apt install --only-upgrade <pkg>]
pkg:[bb-cape-overlays]:[4.14.20201119.0-0~buster+20201123]
WARNING:pkg:[bb-wl18xx-firmware]:[NOT_INSTALLED]
pkg:[kmod]:[26-1]
WARNING:pkg:[librobotcontrol]:[NOT_INSTALLED]
pkg:[firmware-ti-connectivity]:[20190717-2rcnee1~buster+20200305]
groups:[debian : debian adm kmem dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev users systemd-journal input bluetooth netdev gpio pwm eqep remoteproc admin spi iio i2c docker tisdk weston-launch xenomai cloud9ide]
cmdline:[console=ttyO0,115200n8 bone_capemgr.uboot_capemgr_enabled=1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet]
dmesg | grep remote
[   10.849708] remoteproc remoteproc0: wkup_m3 is available
[   11.073021] remoteproc remoteproc1: 4a334000.pru is available
[   11.074751] remoteproc remoteproc2: 4a338000.pru is available
[   11.078998] remoteproc remoteproc0: powering up wkup_m3
[   11.079139] remoteproc remoteproc0: Booting fw image am335x-pm-firmware.elf, size 217168
[   11.083282] remoteproc remoteproc0: remote processor wkup_m3 is now up
dmesg | grep pru
[   11.073021] remoteproc remoteproc1: 4a334000.pru is available
[   11.073193] pru-rproc 4a334000.pru: PRU rproc node /ocp/interconnect@4a000000/segment@0/target-module@300000/pruss@0/pru@34000 probed successfully
[   11.074751] remoteproc remoteproc2: 4a338000.pru is available
[   11.074891] pru-rproc 4a338000.pru: PRU rproc node /ocp/interconnect@4a000000/segment@0/target-module@300000/pruss@0/pru@38000 probed successfully
dmesg | grep pinctrl-single
[    1.762133] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins, size 568
dmesg | grep gpio-of-helper
[    1.776892] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: ready
END
```

Anyone an idea?

thanks
Ju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using SD Card to boot, right?

...

Well, you have two, different versions of uboot on the SD Card and on the eMMC. The eMMC holds presence over the SD Card for uboot when booting.

If you can and if you do not mind losing the data on your eMMC, you can wipe the eMMC of data or press the S2/Boot button while applying power for about 5 seconds.

Also, I thought the ADC lines on the chip were already powered when booting. I do not think you need the overlay for ADC. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I would also unload/comment the pru 4.19.x overlay as you are using 5.4.x instead of 4.19.x.

Comment: I cleaned the eMMC boot partition with
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=1024 count=1024
I disabled the pru overlay
if I disable the adc overlay by uncomment 
disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1 I don't get the /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0 folder

Comment: but still the Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: I think the current kernel that the boards use are 4.19.x and not 5.4.x. If you are just testing with the 5.4.x kernel, okay. But...I would use the 4.19.x kernel instead, i.e. as things just work with that kernel. bbb.io/latest-images have a 2020-04-06 dogtag.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll give that a try going to a 4.19.x kernel.

Comment: Yes, downgrading the kernel did the trick.
Many thanks De Funct

Comment: I am sorry that you have to downgrade kernels to get the iio working on it. I hope there will be future methods on getting it to work w/ the updated kernels.

Comment: Also...you can use these different kernels for what is available at this link: https://github.com/beagleboard/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees . You can alter them and build them accordingly. It may help w/ your current kernel. You can look in the different tags/branches.